# Subsetting by group condition in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set that looks somewhat like this

```
id     year
 1     2012
 1     2014
 1     2015
 2     2014
 2     2018
 2     2019
 3     2011
 4     2010
```

I only want to keep based on these two conditions (1) one observation per id, (2) the latest year of that id. So, for example, for id 1, I only want to have the 2015 row, for id 2, I only want 2019 row, and for id 3 and 4, I only have one observation during those two years so just keep them both.

I have tried a few different things like:

```
df1<-subset(df, interaction(df$id, max(df$year)))
```

I know this subset doesn't make sense but I was just making things up, hoping that something would make sense in my head. Another one I tried,

```
lapply(unique(df$id), function(max) subset(df, mac(year)))
```

but I keep getting errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `slice` the rows where the 'year' is `max` after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(which.max(year))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
#     id  year
#  <int> <int>
#1     1  2015
#2     2  2019
#3     3  2011
#4     4  2010
```

---

If these are the only columns, after grouping by 'id', apply `max` on 'year' to `summarise`

```
df %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     summarise(year = max(year))
```

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(year ~ id, df, FUN = max)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), year = c(2012L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2014L, 2018L, 2019L, 2011L, 2010L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: These are not the only columns but the first code definitely works! Thank you so much!

Comment: then you should mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

You should group and then filter

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(year == max(year)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Differently from the solution with slice proposed by @akrun, this will return all the rows where the year is the max for each id. it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**1) subset/duplicated** Using `df` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and assuming that it is sorted by `year` within `id` (which is the case for the data shown in the question) use `subset` with `duplicated`.  No packages are used.

```
subset(df, !duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE))
##   id year
## 3  1 2015
## 6  2 2019
## 7  3 2011
## 8  4 2010
```

**2) subset/ave** Another way to use `subset` is to use `ave`.  This one does not depend on the input being sorted.

```
subset(df, ave(year, id, FUN = max) == year)
##   id year
## 3  1 2015
## 6  2 2019
## 7  3 2011
## 8  4 2010
```

**3) by** bAnother base approach is to use `by`.  It returns a list of data frames which we `rbind` together.

```
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$id, function(x) x[which.max(x$year), ]))
##   id year
## 1  1 2015
## 2  2 2019
## 3  3 2011
## 4  4 2010
```

**4) tapply** We can use `tapply` if it is ok to return a vector of years whose names are the id's.  Again, this uses only base R.

```
with(df, tapply(year,  id, max))
##    1    2    3    4 
## 2015 2019 2011 2010
```

I had also suggested using `aggregate` but another responder also provided that answer.

### Note

```
Lines <- "id     year
 1     2012
 1     2014
 1     2015
 2     2014
 2     2018
 2     2019
 3     2011
 4     2010"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```